# What is the smallest distance measured that the muon is considered pointlike?

Tags: particle-physics

What is the smallest distance measured that the muon is considered pointlike. I know for the electron it is clost to 0.001 of a femtometer.  It seems to be assumed that this is the same for the muon.  However, I can't find this stat for the muon in a Google search.  My thinking on this is that if their is a muon radius, obviously suggesting substructure that is in the ball park of 0.04 femtometeres, could this affect the lambshift and possible explain the discrepancy in the recent measurements of the proton radius and possibly the anamolous muon magnetic moment?

Comment: I suspect that the results for a muon $(g-2)$ puts stronger limits on this than direct scattering experiments. Those results were improved recently and should improve again now that the Brookhaven instrument has been moved to FNAL to take advantage of a higher current beam.